# Possible to do this in RegEx with Notepad++

Tags: xml, regex

I have a large set of xml data with errors in certain parts of the file. The error is basically that there are lines where there is an `</end>` but not a start to it. I need to find all instances of `</end>` without the start tag and remove them.

So the correct XML data:

```
<Car Name="HONA">
<Group GID="3">
  <Pmeter ParName="*CDMZI" Value="F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456;" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="DMTZ" Value="" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDRFCP" Value="0" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
<Group GID="15">
  <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
```

The incorrect version I need to fix. Note that the `</group`> has no start. I want to remove any `</group>` without a start tag.:

```
<Car Name="HONA">
  <Pmeter ParName="*CDMZI" Value="F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456;" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="DMTZ" Value="" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDRFCP" Value="0" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
<Group GID="15">
  <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
```

Just want to remove only matches of  without a starting  tag, do not want to remove anything in between i.e.  tags.

Comment: Not sure about Notepad++ but Sublime Text is awesome for these tasks.

Comment: do you want to remove only </group> tag or all the <Pmeter> tags above that tag?

Comment: Just want to remove only matches of </Group> without a starting <Group> tag, do not want to remove anything in between i.e. <pmeter> tags.

Comment: @bman2013 It is unclear to me what you are asking. Adding `input` to your question which can be copy-paste to notepad++ and `expected output` will clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Notepad++**

*Find what:* `(<Car\sName=.*>)((\s+<Pmeter\sParName=.*\/>){3})\s+<\/Group>\s+(<Group\sGID.*>(\s+<Pmeter\sParName=.*\/>){3}\s+<\/Group>)`

*Replace with:* `\1\n\4`

[image]

**Input**

```
<Car Name="HONA">
  <Pmeter ParName="*CDMZI" Value="F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456;" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="DMTZ" Value="" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDRFCP" Value="0" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
<Group GID="15">
  <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
```

**Output**

```
<Car Name="HONA">
<Group GID="15">
  <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
```

Note that the output could be changed by changing the `Replace with:` syntax to e.g. `\1\2\n\4` which results in:

```
<Car Name="HONA">
  <Pmeter ParName="*CDMZI" Value="F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456;" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="DMTZ" Value="" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDRFCP" Value="0" Type="A" Flag="P" />
<Group GID="15">
  <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
  <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
</Group>
```

If the output is incorrect, Rubular could be used to get the correct output.

[image]

Comment: @bman2013 Could you add `input` and `expected output` to your question?

Comment: @bman2013 Do you mean that <Group needs to be added to the ones without <Group ?

Comment: @bman2013 The regex works. The `Replace with` should be changed to get the correct output.